# Configuring Outbound email in Alfresco

Tags: email, smtp, alfresco, alfresco-share

I have configured Outbound email in Alfresco, by following this link:
http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/concepts/email-outboundsmtp-props.html

My alfresco-global.properties contains:

```
   ### email server config smtp outbound
    mail.host=emailserver.domain.com
    mail.port=25
    mail.username=example@domain.com
    mail.password=password
    mail.encoding=UTF-8
    mail.from.default=example@domain.com
    mail.smtp.auth=false
    mail.protocol=smtp
    mail.smtp.timeout=30000
```

I get the following error:
No authentication mechanisms supported by both server and client

The same configuration works with Alfresco hosted on a Windows server but doesn't work with Cent OS server.
Any idea what could be the cause ?

Comment: are you sure nothing else is running in port 25. normally sendmail is running.

Comment: You configured the system to use a username/password and tell it not to authenticate. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615730/javamail-exchange for details how your issue most likely can be fixed.

Comment: Hi @TahirMalik, yes I don't think anything else is running on port 25. What do you mean by sendmail? Can you please explain?

Comment: Hi @AndreasSteffan, thanks for the link. I had already tried without giving the username and password to avoid it being trying to authenticate by default, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Seems you are not using TLS, so try "tcpdump -s 0 -A -i any port 25 and host emailserver.domain.com" and capture the output. That should give you an idea what exactly is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your email id which you are using to send emails is less secure#

```
# Outbound Email Configuration
#-------------
mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
mail.port=465
mail.encoding=UTF-8
mail.username=****@gmail.com
mail.password=*******
mail.protocol=smtps
mail.from.default=****@gmail.com
mail.smtps.starttls.enable=true
mail.smtps.auth=true
```